# Телеграм бот на Python путает запросы

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot

Мой бот (смотрите ссылку на Яндекс диск):
https://yadi.sk/d/Q_nrniAjslcIFg

1. принимает текстовые запросы в чате (слова или словосочетания) на различные определения (терминологию)
2. ищет запросы в файле "data" (формат - json) по ключевым словам (keywords).
   По сути json - это dictionary, в котором "name" - это название определения, "keywords" - это слова по которым бот ориентируется в поиске, "links" - похожие определения, которые бот должен предлагать, "answer" - само определение или ссылка в telegra.ph
3. возвращает "answer" и "links"

Проблема: бот путает запросы.
Пример: в файле "data" есть "инвестиционный кредит", у которого в ключевых словах есть "инвестиционный заем". Однако, когда пишешь боту "инвестиционный заем", он возвращает определение "заем"

Проверил код: пропущенных запятых и скобок вроде нет

Кроме того, на некоторые запросы для которых есть ответы, бот вообще не отвечает

код ниже:

```py
import time
import json
import codecs

import telebot
from telebot import types
from telepot.namedtuple import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

from pprint import pprint


Token='mytoken'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)
password = '123'
start = False
alldata = []
unhandled_data = []


def upload_json():
    data = json.load(codecs.open('data.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
    #pprint(data)
    return data

def find_answer(data, request):
    for object in data:
        for question in object['questions']:
            question['count'] = 0
            for keyword in question["keywords"]:
                if keyword in request:
                    question['count'] += 1

    response = []

    for object in data:
        for question in object['questions']:
            if question["count"] > 0:
                response.append(
                    {
                        "name": question['name'],
                        "answer": question['answer'],
                        "count": question["count"],
                        "link": question['link']
                    }
                )

    for i in range(0, len(response)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(response)):
            if response[i]["count"] > response[k]["count"]:
                tmp = response[i]
                response[i] = response[k]
                response[k] = tmp

    return response

def find_answer_byname(data, request):

    for object in data:
        for question in object['questions']:
            question['count'] = 0
            if request == question["name"]:
                question['count'] += 1

    response = []

    for object in data:
        for question in object['questions']:
            if question["count"] > 0:
                response.append(
                    {
                        "name": question['name'],
                        "answer": question['answer'],
                        "count": question["count"],
                        "link": question['link']
                    }
                )

    for i in range(0, len(response)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(response)):
            if response[i]["count"] > response[k]["count"]:
                tmp = response[i]
                response[i]=response[k]
                response[k]=tmp

    print(request)
    print(response)

    return response

def send_answer(message):
    global alldata
    response = alldata

    buttons = []
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if len(response) > 0:
        for link in response[-1]['link']:
            keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=link, callback_data=link))
            buttons.append(link)

    for res in response:
        if res['name'] in buttons:
            res['approve'] = False
        else:
            res['approve'] = True

    if len(response) > 0:
        for res in response:
            if res['approve'] and res != response[-1]:
                keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=res['name'], callback_data=res['name']))

    print("hi " + response[-1]['answer'])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response[-1]['answer'], reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(m):
    global start
    start = True
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте, введите пароль')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def info(m):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Финансовый Регулятор", url="https://finreg.kz/?docid=969&switch=russian&showall")
    keyboard.add(url_button)
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Перейти на официальный сайт", reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(m):
   bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Помогу найти необходимые понятия в области риск-менеджмента')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def handle_text(message):
    global start
    global alldata
    global unhandled_data
    if start:
        global password
        if message.text == password:
            start = False
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верный пароль. Введите термин, который Вас интересует')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неправильный пароль. Попробуйте еще раз')
    else:
        data = upload_json()
        unhandled_data = data
        request = message.text.lower().split(" ")
        print(request)
        response = find_answer(data, request)
        if len(response) > 0:
            alldata = response
            send_answer(message)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У меня нет ответа на этот вопрос')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if not start:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == "test":
                send_answer(call.message)
            else:
                print(call.data[1])
                global alldata
                global unhandled_data
                alldata = find_answer_byname(unhandled_data, call.data)
                send_answer(call.message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```